# What is the connection between the Beyonder race and classic Beyonder?

Tags: marvel, comics, beyonder

I’ve read comic books with pre retcon Beyonder, as well as some with the race of Beyonders, and in one, it references there being ‘ a child unit from the secret wars ‘ who was one. They both come from beyond. So, are the Beyonders the same as classic Beyonder, if not, what is their connection to him? By the way, I noticed they killed all celestials at once, something even classic beyonder could only do one at a time and seemed to at least find it a slightly hard fight.

Comment: Good question. Did you check out the Marvel Wiki article on them?

Comment: The wikipedia article has quite a lot of info too. I'm not sure it's much beyond (haha) what you've already found although it strongly suggests that post-retcon, the Beyonder is one of the Beyonders; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyonders

Comment: Thanks! I checked it and it does seem to suggest that, VERY strongly.